# jQuery children returns a boolean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've come across this line and I can guess what it's doing but shouldn't there be a `length > 0` on the children or will it always return/can be used as a boolean?

Or does jQuery's children return a boolean, or is this person relying on the existence of the returned children?

```
append(($(this).children()) ? '<div class="vAlignWrapper" style="overflow: hidden;">' + $(this).html() + '</div>' : '&nbsp;').
```

I'm trying to debug a large JS file and I'm trying to make sure each line does what its supposed to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like most jQuery methods, `children()` [returns a jQuery object for chaining](http://api.jquery.com/children/). If there are no children, it returns an empty jQuery object.

If you want to know if any children exist or not, you MUST use the `.length` property, which returns a number greater than zero if there are any and zero if there aren't.

So, yes -- it appears the original code was incorrect. Testing `$(this).children()` as a Boolean value will always be considered `true`.

Comment: Ah thanks! It was written by someone more experienced and I was unsure. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

jQuerys [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function will return a jQuery object. This will always be a "truthy" value.

If you want to check if there are any children, you should be using:

```
... ($(this).children().length > 0) ? ...
```

Or, if you enjoy writing cryptic code, this would accomplish the same thing:

```
... $(this).children().length ? ...
```